# Is it possible to hash the password in postfix?

Tags: postfix, microsoft-office-2013

Normally in postfix we will keep the username and password of our account in `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` in plain text format . Is it possible to hash it?

Because when we are sending through gmail it will give us a unique one rather than our original password . But in outlook i dont think that option is there . I know the one way is to change the permissions of that file. But i want know whether hashing of it possible or not?

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Storing some kind of hash here is not possible nor would it be all that helpful if it were. This file contains information required to login to an external service and whichever format this is stored in is by definition enough to get access to that external service. So, it doesn't matter if it is a hash or plain text, if you can read the content of that file, you get access to the service.

Comment: Thanks..Basically the password i am storing here will be my outlook mail password . The persons whoever opening this file will able to see my credentials . My problem is `How can i protect it`?

Comment: Make it readable only by the postfix user.